# Public access local IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET application which uses the local IIS server.

the url is the following:

**http://localhost/myasp/**

It's working properly.

If I replace the localhost with 127.0.0.1 ip address the app still working properly.

But if I check the ip address of my PC, for instance 122.33.21.23

and I try to use it instead of localhost, the internet explorer cannot display the page.

Should I use some special settings in IIS?

I use IIS7 and WIN 7.

Anybody can help me?

l.

Comment: you could add a binding in IIS for your IP, although i dont see the point, just use localhost.

Comment: See also [How do I make my home IIS server accessible from the web?](http://superuser.com/q/434201/180163) and [How can I make my home PC a web server?](http://superuser.com/q/21931/180163)

Answer (score 7):

You have to let IIS pass throw your firewall.

First you have to know the port on which your site is running. Usually your address is like 127.0.0.1:82, 82 being the port number. If is nothing it may be 80. To be sure, go to IIS manager, and in the left expand Sites, R click on your site, Edit Bindings, and you will see the port no.

Go to CP -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced settings -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule...
Select port, TCP, your port number and a name.
Also make sure that if you have another firewall, add an exception for it too, or disable it.

If you have a router, it should work for your network IP (like 192.168...).
To enter on you site with you public IP you will also have to enable "Port forwarding" for your port, or try to connect directly to internet.

Answer (score 0):

As RPM1984 commented it could be a binding issues on IIS7. You may also want to check your windows firewall to see if it is blocking access. You can test by disabling the firewall to see if it makes a different.